# Android UI Multiple Views

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

Is there any way to design the circular button on the end line of the parent layout? It should be half in both the views. Something like this:

[image: example]

I've tried using Constraint Layout but it still does not seem to work. I would prefer Relative Layout. Have tried using `dp` and `dip` but still no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using several linear layouts and setting the round button as a fab and set it at the end of the linear layout containing the text input layouts...!

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'parent layout' and the circle as child views in a relative layout. Then give the 'parent layout' a bottom margin equal to the radius of the circle.

View structure

```
Relative Layout
-White Parent Layout (with bottom margin equal to radius)
-Circle (align parent bottom)
```